# Regsvr32.exe error

Tags: windows, dll, regsvr32

i tried to use Regsvr32 in windows 8 to register a dll file in Syswow 64 but i'm having the following error : The module "file.dll" may not compatible with the version of windows that you're running.check if the module is compatible with an x86(32-bit) or (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe.

i'll be greatful for any proposed help

Comment: You need to use c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe, the 32-bit version is required to register a 32-bit dll.

Comment: i'm using the following line command  "C:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe iec61850.dll" but i'm still having the same problem

Comment: Then try "C:\windows\System32\regsvr32.exe"