# SDL2_ttf can't find entry point unless libfreetype-6.dll is in proj folder

Tags: dll, sdl-2

I am working with SDL2 and its add-on libraries SDL2_image and SDL2_ttf, using Visual Studio 2017.  The libraries, and the .dll files that come with them, are in another folder (C:\SDL2.0\lib\x86), which is in the system path.

When I run, it fails, with this error message:

> The procedure entry point InterlockedCompareExchange@12 could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\SDL2.0\lib\x86\SDL2.ttf.dll.

I can fix this by putting libfreetype-6.dll, which comes with SDL2_ttf, in the same folder as the .vcxproj file; or in the Debug folder.  I can also fix it by putting the .dll into c:\windows\SysWOW64.  But I want to distribute my code, and I don't want to put that file in each folder *or* require users to have admin access (to access c:\windows\SysWOW64); I want Windows to find it in the PATH, as it does with the other .dll files it's using here.

A few things I tried as I looked around the web for solution (to no effect):

- Recompiling libfreetype-6.dll
- Downloading the latest versions of all associated libraries
- Rearranging the .lib files in Project Properties, Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies.  Admittedly I may not have tried all possible arrangements as there are several dependencies
- `regsvr32 libfreetype-6.dll`.  This led to a different error message:
  `The module "libfreetype-6.dll" may not be compatible with the version of Windows that you're running.  Check if the module is compatible with an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe.`
  I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041387/regsvr32-exe-error) that maybe I should use the version of regsvr32 in the system32 folder; when I do that, I get
  `The module "libfreetype-6.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.  Make sure that "libfreetype-6.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.`

So:  is there a way to get the program to find libfreetype-6.dll in another folder in the PATH, and eliminate the error message about the procedure entry point?

The program I'm testing on now is from the TrueType [tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/16_true_type_fonts/index.php) from the LazyFoo website ([source](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/16_true_type_fonts/16_true_type_fonts.zip)).

Comment: I don't understand, what's wrong with putting the DLL next to the executable?

Comment: When you run from Visual Studio, you can change the "current working directory", which I think is the project directory by default

Comment: I would imagine changing the cwd from project directory to something in the PATH would make VS unable to find the project, so I'm not sure about that --?

Comment: My crystal ball says you have yet another, different version of `libfreetype-6.dll` somewhere in your PATH. Find and delete it, or remove that directory from PATH.

Comment: *"But I want to distribute my code, and I don't want to put that file in each folder or require users to have admin access (to access c:\windows\SysWOW64); I want Windows to find it in the PATH, as it does with the other .dll files it's using here."* I don't understand this part. What is *"each folder"*?

Comment: It's a suite of multiple programs, with each in a different folder -- at least 50 programs.  Many or most users will be newbies, which explains why I'm trying to keep it simple, FWIW.  Anyway--

Comment: I'm going to poke around to be sure, but it's looking like your crystal ball may have nailed it...

Comment: OK, I'm sure:  tested it on 2 different computers with the problem; they had different programs in the path with the troublesome .dll, but in each case removing them fixed the problem.  Whew!  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it!